# Cannot refer to table in public schema by different schema

Tags: postgresql, database-design, partitioning, database-partitioning, postgresql-12

I have the following [example](https://joaodlf.com/postgresql-10-partitions-of-partitions.html) :

```
CREATE TABLE dt_totals (
    dt_total date NOT NULL,
    geo varchar(2) not null,
    impressions integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    sales integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt_total);



CREATE TABLE dt_totals_201801
PARTITION OF dt_totals
FOR VALUES FROM ('2018-01-01') TO ('2018-01-31')
PARTITION BY LIST (geo);


CREATE TABLE dt_totals_UK_201801 PARTITION OF dt_totals_201801 FOR VALUES IN ('UK');
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_US_201801 PARTITION OF dt_totals_201801 FOR VALUES IN ('US');
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_AU_201801 PARTITION OF dt_totals_201801 FOR VALUES IN ('AU');
```

in my environment generate a schema called level_part;

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS level_part
    AUTHORIZATION postgres;
```

So far so good, I generate the main partitioned table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS level_part.dt_totals
(
    dt_total date NOT NULL,
    geo character varying(2) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    impressions integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    sales integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) PARTITION BY RANGE (dt_total);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS level_part.dt_totals
    OWNER to postgres;

-- Partitions SQL

CREATE TABLE public.dt_totals_201801 PARTITION OF level_part.dt_totals
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2018-01-01') TO ('2018-01-31')
    PARTITION BY LIST (geo);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.dt_totals_201801
    OWNER to postgres;
```

#### Questions

- Why does it point to the public schema
- is it a pgadmin error ?

and when I try to generate a partition as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_AU_201801 PARTITION OF level_part.dt_totals_201801 FOR VALUES IN ('AU');
```

I get an error :

```
ERROR:  relation "level_part.dt_totals_201801" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

but if I change the schema to public, I am able to refer to the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dt_totals_AU_201801 PARTITION OF public.dt_totals_201801 FOR VALUES IN ('AU');
```

Why can I only refer to the table in the public schema?

Comment: Well, you created the table/partition  `dt_totals_201801` in the schema `public` - why do you expect it to be in the schema `level_part`?

Comment: Btw: you should not create all your tables as the superuser. That's a really bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first create the table, you don't specify a schema, so postgres places the table in the public schema.

> "...Tables without [specified] schema name. [...] By default such tables (and other objects) are automatically put into a schema named "public"

More: [5.7.2. The Public Schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ddl-schemas.html)